# not delete the message from email server using synapse in delphi

Tags: delphi, ararat-synapse

I am retrieving emails using synapse in delphi, but the messages are being deleted from the server. How can I retrieve the message without deleting it? Maybe the header only?

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: You do that by not using POP3.

Comment: @Cosmind Prund: Why? POP3 has a separate command for message deletion, the protocol is perfectly ok for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure emails are deleted, but you **do not** used `pop3.Dele(i)`?

I use POP3 with SSL and if I want to delete message then I had to use `pop3.Dele(i)`. In Synapse wiki: http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/public:howto:pop3samplessl there is my sample code to receive POP3 messages.

Maybe you use other protocol than POP3 then show us your code.

Comment: I don't see `dele()` so it should not delete any message. I will try to check it with my test mail server. Do you have access to mail server logs? Can you use tools such as Wireshark or some kind of tunel to see plain text messages exchanged by client and server?

Comment: sorry comenting so late. I don't have access neither can use wireshark right now. I quit from using delphi to accomplish this task, it was easier to create this logic in php and then use delphi just to fetch a page. But thanks anyway. The php is not deleting the messages thou

Answer (score 1):

I have no hands-on experience with Synapse, but looking at the code (sourceforge trunk) you should be fine as long as you don't explicitly call the Dele method (which maps onto the DELE POP3 command). None of the other methods seems to delete the messages, including List and Retr.

How exactly are you retrieving those messages? Could you show some code?

Comment: i just compiled the source example from the synapse website